# I did user authentication and in the localhost it works fine but on the server I'm getting this error:: Class '\app\models\User' not found

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When running the project online,this is the marked area:

```
$this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the \models\User.php exist on server

Second Could be you are using windows  in localhost and Linux/Unix on server  ..
in this case check for correct Case charecter in you class ..  could be you have

```
   `user.php`
```

instead of

```
 `User.php'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reminder, it has worked, I noticed that \models\User.php contained 'user.php' will lowercase. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure its included properly like added namespace with proper character case and good to go